# problems with a git repo inside another git repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

I know we are not to supposed to create a git repo inside an existing repo, and I know about the submodules in git.
This is just out of curiosity:
Will it cause problems if I create a git repo inside an existing repo?
If yes, what are the side effects? (I want to know what happens?)

Comment: You *can't* put a repository inside a repository. Git forbids it (administratively, as it were). There have been some bugs in the past where you could "trick" Git into storing a repository inside a repository, but you're not supposed to try it, and newer versions of Git will refuse to work with such a repository.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.